# Line integration in pauls notes calculus III

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

[image]

Why did he use $[0,2]$ as the limits of integration in the 3ed curve after substituting the value of $x = 1$ in $x$, shouldn't the limits be $[0,1]$ as in the $X$ axis,  so the last integration becomes $4$ ?

Please correct me if I am wrong .. Thanks

Comment: Because $y$ goes from $0$ to $2$.

Comment: Hi, I think I figured it out,  the integration limits are 0 to 2 y-axis , but since no y in the function and x=1 , it is correct .. I will leave the question in case someone else come across .. Thank you ❤️

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics SE. Images provided in the form of a link doesn't get a good response often. Try to type it in MathJax, so that the question is accessible to readers at one go.